# How to conditionally delete generated javascript files?

Tags: gulp

I'm working with Intellij, which by default transpiles typescript files into js files in the same dir as the typescript source (so transpiling foo.ts produces foo.js).  However, I also have some javascript files that are source files (not generated from typescript) that I don't want to inadvertently delete.

**Example**:

```
   someDir\foo.ts          // original ts source file
   someDir\foo.js          // generated by intellij tsc compile, should be deleted
   someDir\bar.js          // original js sourcefile, should NOTbe deleted!
```

**Question**: 
I'd like to delete all **/*.js files that have a matching **/*.ts file - in the example above, I'd like to delete foo.js (as it has corresponding foo.ts) but not delete bar.js.  Is there some gulp.src pattern that specify can be used to specify 'all **/*.js files that have a matching **/*.ts file'?  If so, I can just pipe the resulting src stream to del.

Thanks,
Brad

p.s. And I know I can do some advanced Intellij typescript configuration to move the location of the generated js files, but I'd rather work with them in their default location.  Another workaround would be to explicitly exclude the 'source js' files in the source stream (with !), but I'd rather do it with a pattern as it is less brittle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var del = require('del');
var glob = require('glob');

var filter = function(file) {
    return file.replace(/.ts$/, '.js');
};

gulp.task('default', function() {
    return glob('./app/**/*.ts', function(err, files) {
        del(files.map(filter));
    })
});
```

You basically use `glob` to get all your `.ts` files, when you have that, map the resulting array to your filter function. This function replaces all occurences of `.ts` at the end of the file with `.js`, you get a new array with those entries in return. Finally, pass the new globs over to `del`.

Comment: you're welcome :-) If it proves right, please mark my answer as correct for people who stumble upon it in the future :-)

Answer (score 3):

I have solved this with a batch file. This is my approach:

***delete_transpiled.bat***

```
REM This script finds all *.ts files (recursivly in all sub directories)
REM and removes the associated *.js and *.js.map files.
REM the folder "node_modules" is excluded from this process.

@echo off
echo Removing transpiled files. Please wait...

for /R %%I in (*.ts) do (
    (Echo "%%~pI" | FIND /I "node_modules" 1>NUL) || (
        if exist %%~pI%%~nI.js del %%~pI%%~nI.js
        if exist %%~pI%%~nI.js.map del %%~pI%%~nI.js.map
    )
)

echo Done
```